# How to interpret GLSL shader compilation errors

Tags: opengl, glsl

My OpenGL application encounters errors when it compiles my fragment shader program, with output that includes

```
0:4(13): error: syntax error, unexpected BASIC_TYPE_TOK, expecting LOWP or MEDIUMP or HIGHP
```

Specifically, how to interpret the "0:4(13)" prefix to the error message? Anyone know where this is documented? I could not find a description of error message format at the [Khronos Shader Compilation wiki](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader_Compilation).

Comment: line 4, column 13.  The 0 is the placeholder for the script source, which came from a string. 
 It can be configured to be something like 'shader.glsl' if the source came from a filename

Comment: Thank you - is that documented somewhere that you know of?

Comment: @Wyck: Filename or index into the `string` array passed into `glShaderSource()`?